# Is it possible to use endnotes with references in Rmarkdown?

Tags: biblatex, pandoc, rmarkdown

I’m finalizing a draft article for submission to peer review as a pdf. I originally wrote the paper using Rmarkdown with footnotes that include citations but I now need to convert the footnotes to endnotes. There doesn't seem to be a clear Rmarkdown conversion so I had to use LaTex code using the following format:

> \endnote{I do not consider a Spatial Lag of Y model because these models are difficult to interpret [@Ruttenauer2019] and because any spatial autocorrelation in outcome will be captured in the error term in either an SDEM or SEM [@LeSage2014].}

Unfortunately, the citations are no longer rendered correctly and just appear in text `(i.e.,  @Ruttenauer2019)` instead of being properly included in the citation. I found [this explanation](https://crimebythenumbers.com/r-markdown.html#footnotes) that describes why the citations no longer work when using this LaTex formatting.

I see two possible solutions: Either (1) I use the traditional ^[ ] format Rmarkdown and they render as endnotes or (2) how to get LaTex to read my citations somehow?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Below is a sample of the YAML and a cut down version of the endnote issue. It's odd to me there's not a clear solution, because endnotes are common enough and usually include citations:

```
---
  title: "Paper title"
author: 
  - Kasey Zapatka^[University of California, Berkeley, 410 Social Sciences Building, Berkeley, CA 
date: " `r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
csl: ASA_format.csl
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
  toc: no
fig_caption: yes
latex_engine: xelatex
keep_tex: true
geometry:
  - top=1in
- bottom=1in
- right=1in
- left=1in
bibliography: "references/manuscript.bib"
link-citations: yes
mainfont: Times New Roman
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \newcommand{\beginsupplement}{\setcounter{table}{0}  \renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}} \setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}}
- \usepackage{lineno}
- \setlength\parindent{24pt}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{enotez}
abstract: |
  
  abstract text...
  
---
  
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagebreak

\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\rfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\doublespacing
  
Sample text  \endnote{While there is an important distinction... I support this approach [@Ruttenauer2019]}. 


\newpage
\singlespacing

\printendnotes
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem: Mix apples with oranges. Rmarkdown/Quarto  code can contain some LaTeX code at some extent. LaTeX can contain LaTeX and plain text. End dot.  Use  `[@foo]` in a `\endnote{}` is the same problem that using it in a `\mbox{}`, or just typing `\mbox{*foo*}` and expect *`foo`* in cursive, but you will obtain `*foo*` because inside a LateX command, an asterisk is just an asterisk, not a markdown  mark. In the same way, `\mbox{[@foo]}` will produce just `[@foo]`, not a citation. But you can use `\mbox{\autocite{foo}}` in Rmarkdown. Apples with apples mix well.

Second problem: The default  `cite-method` is `citeproc`, that can use bibtex files, but `[@foo]` is not exported to `\cite{foo}` or `\autocite{foo}`. Is exported as raw text or hyperlinked text, to avoid run bibtex or biber, so you should use `natbib` or `biblatex` method to use latex citation commands.

Third problem: CLS styles can be used with citeproc, not with bibtex or biblatex. Recently the `citation-style-language` latex package allow use CLS styles, but Quarto is agnostic about this package, so to you can use it via `header-includes` and use `\cite{foo}` but not `[@foo]`, or stay with the bibtex or biblatex styles.

Fourth problem: Al least with the settings of the MWE below for a Quarto document, you can use  `\autocite{foo}`, but for some reason, not alone in a `\endnote{}`. It work if the same reference is cited also in the  `[@foo]`  or `\autocite{foo}` form in main text, or even in the `nocite` directive in the YAML header.

In summary:  you can use `\autocite` in a endnote, but without CLS and some other constraints:

---

**Note**: Use extension .qmd for the example, as the header are set for the newer Quarto format, not the older Rmarkdown.

---

[image: mwe]

````
---
format: 
  pdf:
    cite-method: biblatex
bibliography: foo.bib
biblio-style: apa
keep-tex: true
nocite: |
  @knitr2014, @knitr2015,  
header-includes:
- \usepackage{enotez}
---

```{r,echo=F}
knitr::write_bib(file="foo.bib",c("knitr"))
```
 
Foo [@R-knitr]. 
\endnote{An end note \autocite{knitr2014}}
\endnote{And another note \autocite{knitr2015}}


\printendnotes
````

Or alternatively,  with a CLS style but without the citation markdown syntax:

````
---
format: pdf
link-citations: true
pdf-engine: lualatex
keep-tex: true
header-includes:
- \usepackage{citation-style-language}
- \cslsetup{style = apa}
- \addbibresource{foo.bib}
- \usepackage{enotez}

---

```{r,echo=F}
knitr::write_bib(file="foo.bib",c("knitr"))
```
Foo \cite{R-knitr} 
\endnote{An end note \cite{knitr2014}}
\endnote{And another note \cite{knitr2015}}

\printendnotes

\printbibliography
````

This manage well cites nested only in a endnote, and the output is nearly the same, but the citation link is not only the year, but also the author, `\printbibliography` cannot take the options of biblatex, the ISBN is not printed, and maybe there are several others differences, so evaluate yourself pros and cons of each approach.